# Proving the Almost Everywhere Divergence of a Sum of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots, \xi_n$ be independent identically distributed random variables, satisfying $P(\xi_i=1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(\xi_i=-1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Define
$$ S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i $$
Prove that
$$ \frac{S_n}{n^\alpha} $$
(1) When $\alpha > \frac12$, converges almost everywhere.

(2) When $\alpha = \frac12$, diverges almost everywhere.

My attempt:
Because $\mathbb{E}(\xi_i) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(\xi_i) = 1$, we can apply the central limit theorem, so that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution. Thus, $\frac{S_n}{n^\alpha} = \frac{S_n}{n^{\frac12}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{\alpha - \frac12}}$, where $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha-\frac12}} \to 0$. Could this prove something?